# when I try to get a json from web api I get Stackoverflow exception

Tags: json, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I have made web api which returns me a collection of Categories from mongodb

```
public class Default1Controller : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Category> Get()
        {
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient();*
            var server = client.GetServer(); 
            var db = server.GetDatabase("local");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<Category>("categories").FindAll().ToList();
            return model;            
        }
    }
```

SO the problem is that when I get the response as xml I get the result. 
But As soon as I write in register method

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"))
```

so when I try to get `JSON` result I get the exception : 
`StackOverFlowException in NewtonSoft.Json.dll`

**EDIT**
Here is the code of My Category class

```
public class Category
    {
        public ObjectId _id;

        public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } 
    }
```

So as you may suppose the problem is that there is problem serializing ObjectID

because if I make random class with two strings property ans return a List of that class there is no problem returning in Json format

Comment: Can post your code for your Category class? Most likely there is a non-serializable property or it may be referencing itself or many other serializing issues.

Comment: Do you want _id to be a field or a property? Serializers generally ignore fields and only use properties, but this is configurable with settings. I would either make it a public property or make it a private field. ObjectId is a class, so you'll need to follow that class to check it's properties. Can you post that class? My bet is that it references a Category which can cause a circular reference. There are settings you can add to the serializer to handle these in different ways.